# Crawling web by Simulating click using Ghost.py

Tags: python, web-crawler, ghost.py

The website i want to crawl have multiple pages which are dynamically loaded and i want to simulate click (without opening browsers as selenium does) and so i m using Ghost.py.

Here is the simple program

```
from ghost import Ghost
import time

ghost = Ghost(wait_timeout=50)
page, extra_resources = ghost.open("http://www.samsung.com/in/consumer/mobile-phone/mobile-phone/viewall")
#ghost.wait_page_loaded()
n=2;
#links=ghost.evaluate("""
#           alist=document.getElementsById('txtViewAll');
#           alist.click;
#            """)
#print type(ghost.click("input#txtViewAll"))
page1, resources = ghost.evaluate("document.getElementById('txtViewAll').click();", expect_loading=True)
time.sleep(20)
print page1
```

**BUT**

**Output** is **None**.

Could someone please help me regarding whats wrong with the program.

Why it is not working?

Comment: For starters, 'pag1' isn't a variable so printing it might not have the effect you want.

Comment: sorry for typing mistake..but while running i used page1

Comment: have this question sovled yet?